# 0x Api Call to get prices in DAI

Tags: 0x

I am an absulute beginner, I'm sure some of you can help me here.

When I send an API call in Python as follows:

```
baseurl = "https://polygon.api.0x.org/swap/v1/prices?sellToken=WETH"
r = requests.get(baseurl)
data = r.json()
print(data)
```

I get the following response:

```
{'total': 6, 'page': 1, 'perPage': 20, 'records': []}
```

How can I access the actual prices of the tokens?

Thanks a lot
Lukas

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify which token you want to buy. Your current request to the `swap/v1/price` endpoint is saying which token you want to sell (WETH) but not which token you want to buy, or how much.

Check out the official [0x docs for this endpoint](https://docs.0x.org/0x-api-swap/api-references/get-swap-v1-price#request). `sellToken` and `buyToken` are *not* optional, meaning you must provide them.

Your `baseurl` variable will look something like this:
`baseurl = "https://polygon.api.0x.org/swap/v1/prices?sellToken=WETH&buyToken=DAI&sellAmount=1000000000000000000"`
Notice I also included the `sellAmount` (in wei). You also need to tell 0x how much of the buy *or* sell token you want to swap.